# I want to cache the results of calls to Sqrt(), which collection should I use for efficiency?

Tags: c#, caching, dictionary, sqrt

In my application, I am calculating atomic distances, which must be precise.  As far as I am aware, the only precise way to do this is by using the square root function.  However, using the square root function has created a bottleneck in my application.

The data processed by the application will be reprocessed several times in the future, so caching the result of sqrt() may increase performance after the first run, but only if the correct efficient collection type is used.  There is likely to be around 20,000 sqrt results stored in the collection.

I am considering Dictionary which would store the query number 'd' and the sqrt() result.  Is this the best solution, would a different collection be better, or should I implement a collection especially for the task?

Comment: what are the chances that you'd run a square root on the exact same number enough times that it'd be worth caching? The memory usage would probably be huge for a minimal gain in performance. The answer would probably be to test what is faster in your exact scenario.

Comment: @DLeh the chance is 100% because the same data (atom x, y, z coordinates) is going to be reused several times for several different tasks.

Comment: One danger here is that Dictionary uses hash codes to find keys, and any sort of inconsistency in the double-precision calculations you use to compute your keys may lead to a lookup failure due to a differing hash code.

Comment: Store it in a `Dictionary<K, V>` if it's accessed only by one thread or in a `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` if you need to use it across multiple threads. At 20k elements I wouldn't worry, since lookup is done in O(1).

Comment: @dbc good point about double being non-precise, however this non-precision will always be static in that case anyway, so not applicable to my use case - however thanks for pointing that point!

Comment: @MarcelN. Well if it will be O(1) then that's great, thanks!

Comment: @Aalawlx: The non-concurrent dictionary [is for sure O(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Not quite sure about the concurrent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as `Dictionary` is O(1) it was the best possibility for caching the `sqrt()` results.